# Jade template. What self option for?

Tags: pug

From documentation:

```
Use a self namespace to hold the locals (false by default)
```

From jade code:

```
var self = locals || {};
```

So, when I pass "self: true" option, jade just copy "locals" into "self" variable.
And in template I can access data via "locals" or "self" varialbe, but can't use data without this varialbes.

When is this useful?

Answer (score 0):

- `if(user)` might throw an error if `user` isn't defined, v.s. `if(self.user)` which will not
- `for(key in self)` can go through all the variables without explicitly knowing their names
- you don't want to pollute variable scope, i.e. you're defining variables in jade files that might override the ones passed in

Comment: In 1st and 2nd case I can use locals variable.